# How to solve an integration when the increment is in absolute value?

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I have seen many solutions of integration of absolute values such as $\int |x| dx$ however how do you proceed when you have something like this $\int x |dx|$. I have been struggling with this for quite some time:

## The problem:

I want to postulate a decay exponential functions such: 
\begin{gather}
y  = a (1- \exp(-bx))\\
\dot{y} = b (a - y) dx
\end{gather}
where $a$ is the maximum value that $y$ can have and $b$ is just the rate at which this value will be reached. However, when $x < 0 $ $y$ will tend to $\inf$. The next thing I did was to postulate the following rate

\begin{align} 
\dot{y} = b (a - y) |dx| 
\end{align} 
which will plot a decay response for $x>0$ and $x<0$, which it is what I want. The question is: how to integrate this last equation? Thanks!